# rake db:seed only works when in its own rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, attr-encrypted

Here's two commands while using [attr_encrypted](https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted):

```
# Seed fails to populate encrypted fields
rake db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed

# Seed succeeds
rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
rake db:seed
```

When I say that seed 'fails', I mean that the encrypted fields are all blank. When it succeeds, the encrypted fields are populated.

An example from the seeds file:

```
Company.create_with(  
  key: "12345"  
).find_or_create_by(  
  name: "Acme Inc."  
)
```

Why is this happening, and how can I make sure seeds works every time?

Comment: My guess is it needs to reload context / code / db structure.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Is there a way to tell the seed file to reload these things every time?

Comment: it's not the seed file that needs reloading, it's rake.

Comment: Hence my question... it won't be obvious in future if this stuff doesn't work, so is there a way to reload rake (or reload context/code/db structure) after my migrations or before my seed?

Comment: It's just a stab in the dark, though. And yes, you reload everything by running rake another time. :)